# Using ES6 generators from the answer block of a nodejs readline

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of generators and am constructing an example command line 'game' to do so. However, at the second question, the input I enter appears tripled, i.e. 'eee' when 'e' is entered once. What am I doing wrong?

It appears each questionToAnswer function instance creates a new readline interface and does not properly close it, which would explain the tripled input. However, `rl.close;` should close the interface, AFAIK.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const environments = ['forest', 'lava cave', 'island hut', 'mountainside shack', 'valley'];

const questionToAnswer = (q, a = null) => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question(q, (answer) => {
    if (a !== null) console.log(a, answer);
      rl.close;
      theStory.next();
  });
}

function* eventsOfStory(e) {
  console.log('Welcome to the Great Adventure!');
  yield questionToAnswer('What shall ye name your hero? ', 'Alright! Your hero\'s name shall be');
  yield questionToAnswer(`You wake up in a ${environments[Math.floor(Math.random() * environments.length)]}.`);
  yield questionToAnswer('How will you survive?', 'Sounds like a plan!');
  yield endOfStory();
}

const endOfStory = () => {
  console.log('End of story.');
  process.exit();
}

// iterator
let theStory = eventsOfStory();

theStory.next();
```

The desired result is to have any subsequent event to be triggered after answering the current question or hitting the enter key when a fact is displayed and no answer is expected.

Comment: You really should use promises and `async`/`await` syntax for this stuff, not generators.

Comment: Why not create a *single* `readline` instance, and repeatedly call its `question` method?

Comment: @Bergi, that's a good suggestion, I'll reformat the code as an exercise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rl.close;` should be a `rl.close();`.
(`rl.close` is a function, so you need to call it to close the interface)

See [Readline rl.close()](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_close)

e.g.:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const environments = ['forest', 'lava cave', 'island hut', 'mountainside shack', 'valley'];

const questionToAnswer = (q, a = null) => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question(q, (answer) => {
    if (a !== null) console.log(a, answer);
      rl.close();
      theStory.next();
  });
}

function* eventsOfStory(e) {
  console.log('Welcome to the Great Adventure!');
  yield questionToAnswer('What shall ye name your hero? ', 'Alright! Your hero\'s name shall be');
  yield questionToAnswer(`You wake up in a ${environments[Math.floor(Math.random() * environments.length)]}.`);
  yield questionToAnswer('How will you survive?', 'Sounds like a plan!');
  yield endOfStory();
}

const endOfStory = () => {
  console.log('End of story.');
  process.exit();
}

// iterator
let theStory = eventsOfStory();

theStory.next();
```

Comment: Thanks! Easy win ;)

Comment: @Ginzburg Glad i could help :)